# Why render method outside of components and not functions?

Tags: reactjs

I have this component:

```
interface Props {
  email: string;
}
const getErrorMessage = (payload: any) => {
  if (typeof payload.data === 'string') {
    return payload.data;
  } else if (payload.data && 'payloads' in payload.data) {
    return payload.data.errors
      .map(({ title }: { title: string }) => title)
      .join('. ');
  } else {
    return 'Something went wrong.';
  }
};
const ResetPasswordButton: FC<Props> = ({ email }) => {
  const [forgotPassword, { isLoading }] = useForgotPasswordMutation();

  const handleResetPassword: MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = async (
    event: any
  ) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      await forgotPassword({ email: email });

      toast.success('password reset email sent', {
        position: 'bottom-center',
        autoClose: 8000,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true
      });
    } catch (error: any) {
      toast.error(getErrorMessage(error), {
        position: 'bottom-center',
        autoClose: 8000,
        hideProgressBar: true,
        closeOnClick: true,
        pauseOnHover: true
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <button
      className="cursor-pointer text-right text-sm text-inpay-gossamer"
      onClick={handleResetPassword}
      disabled={isLoading}
    >
      Reset Password
    </button>
  );
};

export default ResetPasswordButton;
```

After code review, I was asked to move the getErrorMessage method outside of the component to avoid re-reading and re-evaluating it every time. I am not storing it with useCallback (since I do not have dependencies).

But then, my question is, why not store everything outside of the component, link onClick functions and so on ? Like when is it that it is proper to store something outside or not ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a valid reason. But you can not keep everything outside, for example in your case you have email as props which prevent your function to move outside, you will have to keep it inside your component to read the props data.
There are eslint rules which recommend this anytime you can move a function outside.

[Here is the documentation which explains what I am trying to say](https://react.dev/learn/removing-effect-dependencies#move-static-objects-and-functions-outside-your-component)